# Is there any GUI comparison tool to check folders in two machine?

Tags: diff, software-rec, file-comparison

Some of my dev machine is one network and test machines in different network. Due to this often we are changing code in test machine and validate it then move the code to dev machine.

I know this is inefficient way but there are some limitations in our network.

So i need a good comparison tool which can compare folders between 2 machines. 
I tried winscp ,but there in one side it is windows and other side linux. I need both the side to be different linux machine and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

[ofms](http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/index.shtml) like midnight commander (mc) or krusader are suited to this.

Also the rsync-gui: grsync is neat.